# Compile Error with Excel VBA UserForm Code with SelectionChange

Tags: excel, vba

First time posting here on stackoverflow (so I hope I am following all the rules). I have looked through so many posts here (and Google in general) to find an answer but nothing I have tried worked.

Background on my file:
I have a sheet (sheet1) with a list of projects (for the sake of this example let's just say Apple, Banana, Orange etc). They are in column A (A2:A77 to be exact).

Now on Sheet2, I would like to have a UserForm pop up when you click on specific cells (Let's say A2:A50 on sheet2). When the UserForm pops up, there is one dropdown list with a searchable list (combobox) and one button (basically where you "accept" the selection which is then added to the cell you have selected). I have found a template on this website (http://boisgontierjacques.free.fr/pages_site/listes_cascade.htm#ListeIntuitiveForm) that does EXACTLY what I want. The website is in French but basically it is the link to the template called "Recherche Intuitive TextBox ListBox Form".

As mentioned above, I have copied the code exactly as it is from the template. I have made sure the namings are the same, named range, etc but nothing worked. I have tried changing part of the codes (Setting it to a range, setting up the variable etc but always get an error).

Here is the code I have in Sheet2 (where you click on the cells for the userform to pop up):

```
Private Sub WorkSheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target as Range)
If Not Intersect ([A2:A50]), Target) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then
    UserForm4.Left = Target.Left + 150
    UserForm4.Top = Target.Top + 90 - Cells(ActiveWindow.ScrollRow, 1).Top
    UserForm.Show
End If
End Sub
```

This is the code I have for the UserForm (I already double checked naming of the objects, they are the same):

```
Dim a()
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Set a = [Liste]
  Me.ComboBox1.List = a
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  Set d1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  tmp = UCase(Me.ComboBox1) & "*"
  For Each c In a
    If UCase(c) Like tmp Then d1(c) = ""
  Next c
  Me.ComboBox1.List = d1.keys
  Me.ComboBox1.DropDown
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  ActiveCell = Me.ComboBox1
  Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
  If KeyCode = 13 Then ActiveCell = Me.ComboBox1: Unload Me
End Sub
```

The template mentioned above includes the code, the UserForm, the list etc but for some reason when I try to replicate it, it gives me errors. It started with error 424 (I got around that), then error 91 (also got around that) but now it is giving me a "Compile error: Can't assign to array" error.

When I try to debug (F8), it highlights this part of the code:

`Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` - this is highlighted in yellow

`a = [Liste].Value` (this is the original version and gives me the 424 error;

when I change it to `Set a = [Liste]` (one of the recommendations I found online) it highlights `a=` in blue and gives me the compile error.

The code works fine in the template workbook from the website but I just can't figure out why it doesn't work in mine.

Thank you you so much for your help, I have trying to solve this for hours now!

Comment: What is `[Liste]`? Which range? If you do `Set a = [Liste]` you try to assign a `Range` object to an array `Dim a()` which cannot work. So it must be `a = [Liste].Value` to get the values into the array. Probably a range with the name `Liste` does not exist in the sheet.

Comment: I feel so stupid now. I was just about to write an explanation about how I set up the named range [Liste] with a formula (offset formula) and realized that I had a typo in the formula (Shet1 instead of Sheet1). Once I changed it, it worked. I feel very silly now but thank you for making me go back and check it! And you are right, I changed the code back to 'a = [Liste]'.Value for it to work

Comment: No worries. Somtimes you just don't see it. Happens to everyone.